# Peticiones a API en distintos puertos en React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api, cors

Estoy aprendiendo React, sin embargo he estado tratando de realizar una consulta a una API que tengo en PHP.

El problema surgio en React al tratar de realizar la petición, a la API, se ejecuta sobre el puerto 3000 (puerto donde esta corriendo la Aplicación de React) y no en el puerto 8080, del servidor Apache.

¿Cómo puedo resolver esta situación? hacer que las peticiones se puedan ejecutar en el puerto adecuado.

Está es mi peticio http

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/config/').then( res=> {
    console.log(res.data)
})
```

Este es el error que se muestra en consola

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/config/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro que es lo que necesitas hacer, pero si tu aplicación en php esta corriendo en el puerto "8080" el código que tienes es correcto, ayudaría que compartieras código del backend para poder entender mejor tu situación.

Comment: El problema está en qué en react al ejecutarse la instrucción de la petición, la realiza al puerto 3000 (localhost:300) a pesar que específico en la URL de axios que sea el puerto 8080. La API funciona bien ya que la estoy usando en una app mobil.

Comment: Otro problema puede que ser que el puerto 8080 es muy usado para phpmyadmin, intenta montar tu backend en un puerto distinto como el 4000, pues que axios detecte el puerto 8080 y redireccione la petición